Custom GUI app for hotspotshield issue on Linux
I'm trying to build a custom GUI app on Python for hotspotshield VPN, a bit like this one, but more fitted for my needs: https://github.com/kiraitachi/PyShieldGUI
I am having an issue with sending commands to the terminal. Though the commands works in the terminal, I can't seem to make it work in Python.
I am new to linux, so there may be some things I don't understand about it...
I have tried subprocess.run and subprocess.Popen, but both seem to have issues with sending the commands. The issue is the same when using the PyShieldGUI code.
Here's my latest attempt, which seems the closest to running:
command = ["hotspotshield", "account", "signin"]  ## (I tried both a string and a list)
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
process.stdin.write(f"{username}/n")
process.stdin.write(f"{password}/n")
process.stdin.flush()

stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

When trying the function, i get a "account: line 1: hotspotshield: command not found"
For what it's worth, I did confirm that the executable for hotspotshield is in the PATH.

One obvious problem is that you are using /n instead of \n. Generally you should prefer subprocess.run over subprocess.Popen (you will want to pass the input as a single string with input=f"{username}\n{password}\n") ... But most fundamentally, the error message seems to be saying that hotspotshield is not on your PATH. The account: at the beginning is confounding, though. Does hotspotshield end up trying to execute itself with a modified PATH or something?

Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538  for some common subprocess FAQs.
